# Setting for multiple monitors so mouse can always go from one screen to another?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I have a newer monitor (1920x1080) and and older one that's 1600x1200.

The 1600x1200 is the main desktop.  Under Windows XP, that means there's a small "wall" of 120 px where the mouse can't get from one screen to the other.

Is there any way to configure it so that it will allow it to move into the other screen without the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those displays, there will always be a difference of 120 vertical pixels. You can move the "wall" to the top or bottom of the screen, or a mixture. In [Display Properties](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307873) in Control Panel:

> Click the monitor icons and drag them to positions that represent how
>   you want to move items from one monitor to another, and then click OK
>   or Apply to view changes.

I have a similar arrangement and I prefer to have this gap at the top of the (primary) 1600x1200 display, with the other display on the right, and aligned to the bottom. This makes it easier to close windows that are maximised on *either* display, thanks to [Fitts's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law).

Comment: This is correct, you can't get rid of it but the exact alignment of those thumbnails correlates to where the overlap would be.  There's no way to not do this - it might help to think, instead of how your mouse cursor moves, how you would expect windows to overlap the screens.  There has to be a 1:1 correlation in pixels or the laws of reality break down!

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) to configure specific size screen resolutions and positioning among other settings. You can download a free trial.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer to show why Ultramon helps with this particular scenario. I don't understand why there is a downvote, however.

Comment: I downvoted this. The answer clearly doesn't understand the question - Ultramon doesn't somehow magically make your monitors overlap in places they can't.  (It may make configuring them a bit easier, but it doesn't actually do anything in terms of monitor resolution and arrangement that you can't do without it.)  See my comment on sblair's answer.

Comment: It doesn't "magically" make your monitors overlap and that's not what I was suggesting, now was I? I said you can use it to configure specific size screen resolutions and positioning. Here's a link to exactly what i was talking about under the features to the original link i posted...

http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp

Comment: @Split71 - I didn't say you did (at least not deliberately).  My point was that your answer didn't really directly address the question.  It provides a good tool, but doesn't actually address the question "Is there any way to configure it so that it will allow it to move into the other screen without the wall?".  You're just saying "Here's another way to arrange your screens!" but not answering the question.  Ergo, it's just not a good answer.